# Как отцентровать View в ConstainLayout

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева то что сейчас. Справа то что я хочу добиться.

В LinearLayout это делается просто. gravity=center_vertical. А как такое сделать в ConstainLayout?

В принцйипе я могу сверху и снизу сдеклать 2 View пустых. И сделать им match_parent. Но это не красиво смотриться будет. Может как то через ConstainLayout можно это сделать?

---

Я сделал так но видимо это не то.

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background_login">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Online Video Training"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="Welcome"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Please Login"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="24dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etLogin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPass"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etLogin"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etLogin"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/remember_me"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etPass"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="24dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:text="Log In"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox"
            />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Гавно код какой то получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается просто с `wrap_content` и `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` + `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.33"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />
```

выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кажется это не то. Я скинул обнову выше. Гляньте плиз